# VPC creation problem in aws via terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I have been trying to create vpc infrastructure in AWS through terraform I am unable to perform the "Terraform apply" command anyone has a similar problem while using a free trial account.

Error: Error creating VPC: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: 4HZVo3-eWCS-YLhRy55P_0T13F_fPtA29TYrJrSe5_dyPxIcqRbh7_wCcrCZr2cpmb-B5--_fxVaOngBfHD_7yfnPH7NLf1rrqpb7ge1mvQrK8P0Ltfpgpm37nZXezZUoYf1t4peB25aCxnbfeboHpgJjcFnHvqvf5so5G2PufnGZSB4FUZMfdaqppnJ-sNT7b36TonHUDNbLhBVUl5Fwd8d02R-6ZraRYvDx-o4lDfP9xSWs6PMUFXNr1qzruYaeMYMxIe-9kGOQptgBLYZXsxr966ajor-p6aLJAKlIwPGN7Iz7v893oGpGgz_8wxTv4oEb5GnfYOuPOqSyEMLKI69b2JUvVU1m4tCcjKBaHJARP5sIiFSGhh4lb_E0_cKkmmFfKzyET2h8YkSD8U9Lm4rRtGbAEJvIoDZYDkNxlW7W2XvsccmLnQFeSxpLolVhguExkP7DT9uXffJzFEjQn-VkhqKnWlwv0vxIcOcoLP04Li5WAqRRr3l7yK2bYznfg
│       status code: 403, request id: 5c297a4d-7bcf-4bb4-b311-37480e1f26b8

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). We need much more information.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have properly setup aws credentials and permissions.

check these two files

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

```
~/.aws/config
```

this docs can help you.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

Comment: THANK YOU: I HAVE SOLVED THE PROBLEM USING THE CHANGE INSTANCE PERMISSION FOR USER:

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your access keys?

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-2"
  access_key = "my-access-key"
  secret_key = "my-secret-key"
}
```

There are multiple ways to do it (described [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs)).

My above example can be a good start but you don't want to commit those so I recommend to configure the keys in `~/.aws/credentials` (like you need them for AWS CLI). The `aws` provider will pick them up automatically and so you don't need to define them somewhere in your terraform code.